# Dynamically call Export-ModuleMember

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

Can you tell me why the following code does not export any functions:

```
# load all functions
$moduleRoot = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$functionFiles = "$moduleRoot\functions\*.ps1" | Resolve-Path
$functionFiles | ForEach-Object { . $_.ProviderPath }
$functionFiles | ForEach-Object { [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) } | Export-ModuleMember
```

Or the difference between this:

Not working:

```
$test = "Cmd1", "Cmd2"
Export-ModuleMember $test
```

Working:

```
Export-ModuleMember "Cmd1", "Cmd2"
```

**UPDATE:**

When calling "import-module MyCrazyModule", I can see the exported commands (get-module).

However, when calling "get-module -ListAvailable", the exported commands property is empty. (the module is in the PSModulePath)

**UPDATE 2: Evidence**

$PSModulePath contains D:\powershell

Module: "D:\powershell\MyCrazyModule\MyCrazyModule.psm1"

```
$test = "Cmd1", "Cmd2"
Export-ModuleMember $test
```

No exports visible:

[image]

However with content

```
Export-ModuleMember "Cmd1", "Cmd2"
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide evidence that this `$test = "Cmd1", "Cmd2"; Export-ModuleMember $test` does not work? Because it work for me: `New-Module { function Cmd1 { 'Cmd1' } function Cmd2 { 'Cmd2' } function Cmd3 { 'Cmd3' } $test = "Cmd1", "Cmd2"; Export-ModuleMember $test}`

Comment: @PetSerAl added the evidence

Comment: @Jonas does it work with `Export-ModuleMember -Function $test`? It should work with what you originally described.

Comment: @Nkosi No, it does not either  ;-)

Comment: @Jonas What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: `get-module -ListAvailable` does not execute you module. It only parse syntax tree of script and try to "guess" what commands your module will export if properly imported. Of course, it fail to "guess" any dynamic command. It just not designed to be accurate. For example, that `if($true) { function f { } }` will export function `f`, but it will not be listed with `-ListAvailable` switch.

Comment: @PetSerAl Ok, so, I'll have to explicitly export my functions if I want to use the "implicit import". Thanks

Comment: @Nkosi I want a module where each function is in its own file, the ability to implicitly import the module and I really wanted to avoid repeating the Export-ModuleMember for each file. But there is no way around it if I want to be able to use the implicit import. It's not like it's a big deal, but yeah...

Comment: @Jonas your assessment is correct as that cmdlet can be used only in a script module file or a dynamic module. Each file will have to have its on export.